# Export chart image data locally in HIghchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts implementation. I need to be able to get the image data in my source code at client side. How can this be done?
I know there are `exportChart` methods, but they directly trigger a download and does not return an image in the source code.
I have also read about getting SVG from the chart and then converting that into an image, but that seems to be a workaround rather than a solution. Can this be done in a proper way or is there anything available in Highcharts for this?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: I did not get a direct solution to this. What I did is to export the SVG from the chart and then use that SVG to render an image on the canvas. Then generate the image from the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use `offline exporting` module (http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.src.js)? It will allow you to export image without sending any data to an external server (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export).

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.exportChartLocal

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9dom7je9/

Comment: Yes. As I already mentioned I have explored these. My problem is not about sending data to the external server, but when I export, the image is directly downloaded. I am not able to get the image data in my JS code. I need the image in JS code so that I can do further operations with that.

Comment: Any luck here ?